# Div fixada passando atrás das outras

Tags: html, css

Olá, a primeira div do meu site tem a posição fixada (`position:fixed`) e, quando eu rolo para baixo, ela fica atrás dos outros elementos, como imagens e etc. Não funciona nem que eu coloque `position:absolute` ou `position:sticky` , alguém pode me ajudar? 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Adiciona um z-index nela.

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

A ordem natural do *empilhamento* dos elementos é que os inseridos anteriormente na árvore do DOM ficam por baixo dos inseridos posteriormente. É a [ordem do empilhamento](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Com isso, a primeira `div` fixa que você colocou irá ficar por baixo das posteriores ao fazer o scroll. Para alterar isso existe a propriedade `z-index` que altera a ordem de empilhamento de elementos, podendo fazer com que um elemento inserido antes fique por cima de outro inserido posteriormente.

Como a árvore do DOM pode possuir vários níveis de nós, cada nível recebe um `z-index` de acordo com a sua posição, 1, 2, 3 e assim por diante, você pode declarar um `z-index` à sua `div` de forma que garanta que ela ficará por cima das outras, atribuindo um valor suficientemente alto, e esse valor pode depender da estrutura do seu projeto.

Mas, para simplificar, um valor de 9 já pode ser suficiente. Adicione no seu CSS um `z-index: 9` à sua `div`:

```
#minhaDiv{
   z-index: 9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar z-index para definir a ordem  os elementos. Neste caso, que você quer sobrepor todos elementos com sua div, utilize o seguinte:

```
    #suadiv{ 
    z-index: 99; /* 99 para que não tenha duvidas sobre os níveis de sobreposição */
}
```

Você pode conferir mais sobre a propriedade z-index direto no site da W3Schools [Clicando aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).